# How to update html repeated field values to mysql database

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax

I have a html repeated values in array that i need to update to database, i need a help on how to use php script to update to database where staffid mataches . See below my HTML code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head lang="en">
  <meta chartaxt="UTF-8">
  <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <title>Sample salary computation</title>

</head>

<body>
  <form method="POST" name="regis" id="regis">
    <table align="center" border="1" width="200">
      <tr>
        <th>Staff ID</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
        <th>Total Tax</th>
        <th>Total Net Pay</th>


      </tr>

      <!--Staff 1-->
      <tr data-id="STAFF/2016/001">
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="staffid[]" class="staffid" value="STAFF/2016/001" readonly="readonly">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="salary[]" class="salary" placeholder="salary" value="5000">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="tax[]" class="tax" placeholder="tax" value="500">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="total[]" class="total" placeholder="total" readonly="readonly" value="4500">
        </td>
      </tr>

      <!--Staff 2-->

      <tr data-id="STAFF/2016/002">
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="staffid[]" class="staffid" value="STAFF/2016/002" readonly="readonly">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input name="salary[]" class="salary" type="text" placeholder="salary" value="10000">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" placeholder="tax" name="tax[]" class="tax" value="1000">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" placeholder="total" class="total" name="total[]" readonly="readonly" value="9000">
        </td>
      </tr>

      <!--Staff 3-->

      <tr data-id="STAFF/2016/003">
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="staffid[]" class="staffid" value="STAFF/2016/003" readonly="readonly">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input name="salary[]" class="salary" type="text" placeholder="salary" value="8400">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" placeholder="tax" name="tax[]" class="tax" value="400">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" placeholder="total" class="total" name="total[]" readonly="readonly" value="800">
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td width="300">

          <input type="button" name="update" value="Update Values" class="btn btn-danger">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Kindly assist. I want the SQL update query to look like

```
"Update payroll SET salary ='".$_POST['salary']."', tax='".$_POST['tax']."', total ='".$_POST['total']."' WHERE staffid= '".$_POST['staffid']."'"
```

Comment: "I want the SQL update query to look like" Hopefully you wont. Because you are throwing HTTP input variables directly into an SQL string without escaping anything. Please use a prepared statement to query a database using user inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend to rename the input names to create a single array with all the information you need. Use the staff ID as array keys.

```
<!--Staff 1-->
<tr data-id="STAFF/2016/001">
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="staff[STAFF/2016/001][id]" class="staffid" value="STAFF/2016/001" readonly="readonly">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="staff[STAFF/2016/001][salary]" class="salary" placeholder="salary" value="5000">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="staff[STAFF/2016/001][tax]" class="tax" placeholder="tax" value="500">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="staff[STAFF/2016/001][total]" class="total" placeholder="total" readonly="readonly" value="4500">
    </td>
</tr>

<!--Staff 2-->

<tr data-id="STAFF/2016/002">
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="staff[STAFF/2016/002][id]" class="staffid" value="STAFF/2016/002" readonly="readonly">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="staff[STAFF/2016/002][salary]" class="salary" placeholder="salary" value="10000">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="staff[STAFF/2016/002][tax]" placeholder="tax" class="tax" value="1000">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="staff[STAFF/2016/002][total]" placeholder="total" class="total" readonly="readonly" value="9000">
    </td>
</tr>
```

In PHP you can then iterate over this single array:

```
<?php

$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database;', 'root', '');

if (!empty($_POST['staff'])) {
    $stmt = $db->prepare('UPDATE payroll SET salary = :salary, tax = :tax, total = :total WHERE staffid = :staffid');

    foreach ((array)$_POST['staff'] as $staffId => $staffInfo) {

        $stmt->bindValue(':salary', $staffInfo['salary']);
        $stmt->bindValue(':tax', $staffInfo['tax']);
        $stmt->bindValue(':total', $staffInfo['total']);
        $stmt->bindValue(':staffid', $staffId); // you can also use $staffInfo['id'] here instead of $staffId

        $stmt->execute();
    }
}
```

See also:

- http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php
- http://php.net/manual/de/pdo.prepare.php

Comment: Thanks alot Feela. i was able to get it done based on your recommendation above. It was really really helpful